# Download file at given url via nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I can use nginx to proxy data from an upstream server, but how can I use it to proxy data from a url that is passed in via a query string parameter?

This works, but is incomplete:

```
# e.g. http://localhost:8080?u=https://requestb.in/1nm8uv01 -> ok
location / { 
  proxy_pass $arg_u;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
}
```

I'm not encoding that `u` parameter correctly. This is a problem when I start adding query string params to it. For example, this fails:

```
# http://localhost:8080?u=https://requestb.in/1nm8uv01?a=b&c=d
  -> incomplete; c is not passed to the upstream
```

So encode it, right? Encoding the url parameter also fails:

```
# http://localhost:8080/?u=https%3A%2F%2Frequestb.in%2F1nm8uv01%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd
  -> nginx error: invalid URL prefix in "https%3A%2F%2Freq...
```

So if I encode the parameter as in this last example, how do I get nginx to decode it before doing the request?

Comment: Yes! `set_unescape_uri` looks like what I want. It looks like it's part of openresty -- I'll get that and try it. Thank you!

Comment: That did it. I'm all set. Thank you so much!